# Facebook Login SDK

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to make Facebook Login in my app,but I have a misundertanding here.

[image]

[image]

Do I need to download Facebook SDK,if I am importing it in the second part?If yes how should I **import the Facebook SDK packages**

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding `mavenCentral` in your repositories and adding `com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)` to your dependencies, you are adding the Facebook sdk to your application. Make a Gradle build and try some examples.

Answer (score 0):

While Facebook does offer a standalone download of their [Android SDK](https://origincache.facebook.com/developers/resources/?id=facebook-android-sdk-current.zip), you should not need to download anything separately. Adding the [documented changes](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#androidstudio) to your build.gradle files should be sufficient to get your project going with the latest Facebook Android SDK.